# How to update data from ajax call (chart.js)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chart.js

I manage to generate a graph from an ajax call coming from a php file.
I want to modify this graphic from the selection of the customers field (chg_customer) via a drop-down list. My drop-down list works and shows the names of the customers. However, I cannot generate a new chart from this selection with the right number (count) corresponding to the right customer. Can you help me ? thank you

html :

```
<select id="filter"> 
<option>Tous</option>
</select> 
<canvas id="graph4Canvas" style="height: 700px; width: 100%;"></canvas></select>
```

graph.js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'graph4.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

            var chg_customer = [];
            var count = [];
            for (var i in data) {
                chg_customer.push(data[i].chg_customer);
                count.push(data[i].count);
            }

            var ctx = $('#graph4Canvas');

            const barGraph = new Chart(document.getElementById('graph4Canvas'), {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: data.map(o => o.chg_customer),
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Clients',
                        data: data.map(o => o.count),
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)",
                        yAxisID: 'Nombres',
                        xAxisID: 'Clients',
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            id: "Nombres",
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                stepSize: 1,
                                fontSize: 15,

                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Nombres'
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                drawOnChartArea: false
                            },
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                            id: "Clients",
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                stepSize: 1,
                                fontSize: 10,

                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: false,
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                drawOnChartArea: false
                            },
                        }],
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                },
            });


            data.forEach(o => {
                const opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = o.chg_customer;
                opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(o.chg_customer));
                document.getElementById('filter').appendChild(opt);
            });


            $("#filter").change(function() {
                //update data 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a need to generate a new chart. Once the chart exists all you need to do is to edit the datasets and call the chart update function to re-render the chart.

e.g (example is using angular in my case but still should apply):

HTML:

```
<mat-select [(value)]="selectedFilter" (selectionChange)="filterStreamType()">
```

JS:

```
public filterStreamType() {
    // code manipulates data....
    this.chart.data.datasets = newData; // update our dataset so chart js can re-draw it   
    this.chart.update(); // This is a redundant call but I did a bad job here and mixed some things that should not be mixed and so
}
```

Also note that between V2 and V3 there have been breaking changes so this syntax may vary a bit depending on the version you use.